# Difference in archive formats?

Tags: catalina, compression, archive-utility

After a little testing, I can't figure out what the difference is in the archive formats listed in the Preferences > Use archive format. Each time I compress a folder, each one has the same extension and file size. Can someone shed some light on this?

[image: Screenshot of Archive Utility Preferences window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Archive Utility Preferences

Use archive format:

- Zip archive: A Zip file (`.zip`).
- regular archive: [ASCII cpio archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpio) (`.cpio`).
- compressed archive: An ASCII cpio archive, but gzip compressed (`.cpgz`).

Note that the `Compress "folder"` option in Finder always creates a zip file. To use the other options you have to open Archive Utility directly and drag-and-drop things onto the icon in the Dock.